# Is the Kotlin Structured Concurrency [coroutine] model scoped to UI suitable for DB writes?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel, kotlin-coroutines

*I'm specifically concerned about inserting user initiated data into the local database.*

The following pattern is prevalent in examples (including from official sources, e.g. JetBrains, Google/Android) for using Kotlin coroutines in conjunction with [Android Architecture Components] ViewModels.

```
class CoroutineScopedViewModel : ViewModel(), CoroutineScope {
    private val _job = Job()
    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = Dispatchers.Main + _job

    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        _job.cancel()
    }

    fun thisIsCalledFromTheUI() = launch {
        /* do some UI stuff on the main thread */
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            try {
                /* do some IO, e.g. inserting into DB */
            } catch (error: IOException) {
                /* do some exception handling */
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's my understanding of the [documentation](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/ui/coroutines-guide-ui.md#structured-concurrency-lifecycle-and-coroutine-parent-child-hierarchy) that in the above example the coroutines started in the UI context (defined through  `coroutineContext`) will be cancelled when the `ViewModel` is destroyed, but that the code in the `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` block will get to run to completion.

But, before I go about refactoring my project from the (pre-1.0.0) globally scoped (launch/async) coroutine model, I feel I need to just have some things clarified:

Is my reading of the documentation correct? Or, will destruction of the viewmodel before the  `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` block runs to completion  trigger cancellation of that job too? I.e. can this model be used for inserting data into my DB, or could some strange timing issue arise where the user hits back or otherwise causes the ViewModel owner to close that ends up losing the data?

I don't want to inadvertently introduce a timing bug because I misunderstood something and therefor converted my code to a model similar to the one shown above.

#### EDIT:

So, I decided to do a little test, and it seems to me that all those examples using this model to write to the database may have a fundamental bug.

Modifying the code to log what happens, as such:

```
class ChildViewModel : ViewModel(), CoroutineScope {
    private val _job = Job()
    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = Dispatchers.Main + _job

    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        Log.d("onCleared", "Start")
        _job.cancel()
        Log.d("onCleared", "End")
    }

    fun thisIsCalledFromTheUI() = launch {
        Log.d("thisIsCalledFromTheUI", "Start")
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            Log.d("GlobalScope", "Start")
            delay(15000)
            Log.d("GlobalScope", "End")
        }
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            Log.d("withContext", "Start")
            delay(10000)
            Log.d("withContext", "End")
        }
        Log.d("thisIsCalledFromTheUI", "End")
    }
}
```

Results in this, if you let it run to completion:

```
D/thisIsCalledFromTheUI: Start
D/GlobalScope: Start
D/withContext: Start
D/withContext: End
D/thisIsCalledFromTheUI: End
D/GlobalScope: End
```

But, if you close the Fragment/Activity (not the app) before `withContext` ends, you get this:

```
D/thisIsCalledFromTheUI: Start
D/GlobalScope: Start
D/withContext: Start
D/GlobalScope: End
```

Which indicates, to me at least, that you cannot use this to write non-transient data to the DB.

Answer (score 1):

> It's my understanding of the documentation that in the above example the coroutines started in the UI context (defined through `coroutineContext`) will be cancelled when the `ViewModel` is destroyed, but that the code in the `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` block will get to run to completion.

This isn't a correct reading of the documentation. `withContext` doesn't start another coroutine, it just changes the current coroutine's context for the duration of its block. Therefore this coroutine will get cancelled, as well as all other coroutines you start without providing a new parent context that has a different job associated with it (or no job at all, like the `GlobalScope`).

However, your proposed idea to use the `GlobalScope` for persistent operations is just a local patch for the scenario you're testing, you're still not getting a guarantee it will run to completion. The user can exit the application completely and Android can kill the process.

Therefore, if your goal is building a truly robust application, you must accommodate the fact that, until the coroutine completes, no information was written to the DB. Hopefully you run the operation within a DB transaction that will automatically roll back if your program gets killed, otherwise it will be impossible to prevent inconsistencies.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense but why are so many examples using it?. 
In practice I'm keeping the IO short, writing to the DB and sending it to the back-end (the truly time-consuming operation) using the AAC WorkManager framework. Yes, every relevant DB operation (insert, update) is done in a transaction. An application exit is less concerning to me, as that is something the user is likely to notice, and deal with. The user may have to travel a day to acquire the single datum, don't want a too quick back press or `finish` to necessitate a redo (if it goes unnoticed until they get back).

Comment: This is the sentence from the docs that confuses me:

 "A long-running coroutine, performing some IO or a background computation, can retain references to the corresponding UI elements for longer than it is needed, preventing garbage collection of the whole trees of UI objects that were already destroyed and will not be displayed anymore"

It leaves the impression that one only wants to get rid of the unnecessary UI elements, not get rid of the IO operation.

Comment: Examples use `GlobalScope` because that's what it's for---self-contained examples that you can run standalone. I made it a point to never answer a question here using `GlobalScope`, no matter how simple the code is that I want to show.

Comment: If your DB operation doesn't eventually interact with the GUI in the initiating activity, you don't have to bind it to its lifecycle. For that case you can introduce an application-level scope, bound to the lifecycle of `YouApplication`. This is still better than `GlobalScope`. It allows you to specify `Dispatchers.Main` as the default dispatcher.

Comment: However, you'll still have the issue of holding on to the entire GUI tree of a defunct activity. Try to avoid it by minimizing the amount of code inside the coroutine you `launch`. Don't use any local variables within it that refer (directly or indirectly) to the GUI.

Comment: Sorry, I meant many (most?) `ViewModel` specific examples (that I've seen) use the  `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` approach (not `Global.launch`). Which seems like a potential bug to me.

Comment: If the data validates I write it to the DB and also close the fragment (via a LiveData message to it from the VM). The UI (calling fragment) is updated through notification (LiveData+Room). Messages originating from Exceptions are sent to the UI.

Comment: `Dispatchers.IO` is strictly for making blocking API calls. It makes sense when updating the `ViewModel` from the results of such a call, but otherwise it's pointless and wrong.